# Symfony Acl voters always grant access

Tags: symfony, acl

I use symfony acls. It work great.
But for some entities, I use custom voter because rules are simple and not managed.
I want to use same actions names as  EDIT, CREATE etc and isGranted.

When voters are called, custom voter work fine but acl voters always grant access : 
Object identity unavailable. Voting to grant access

I don't understand this behavior.
I think acl voters should abstain if there is no object identity.

There is a parameter : $allowIfObjectIdentityUnavailable, default value to true
Why ? How can I change this value ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

This is possible: in your `security.yml` configuration you can set:

`security:
   acl:
     voter:
       allow_if_object_identity_unavailable: false`